# String validation using regex posix class

Tags: bash, regular-expression, string, posix

I'm trying to build validation for an address field in a file

The file is like so;

```
123 Strata Ln.
15 138th Ave
27 Hilltop Dr. Apt. 7
F52 Milk Ln.
156A Fantastic St.
56 sample Ln.
```

These are the conditions:

Number​ - at least one digit, followed by an arbitrary number of
additional digits

Street Name​ - An arbitrary number of words (at least one) each beginning
with a capital letter or number, followed by any number of lower and
upper case letters, numbers, or periods (.)

EDIT: With these conditions, only the first three lines of the file are valid

Here's what i've tried

`'^[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]+ ([[:upper:]]|[[:digit:]])([[:alphabet:]]|[[:digit:]])+\.$'`

but it doesn't seem to work. Any help?

Comment: `[[:alphabet:]]` is not valid.  You probably want `[[:alpha:]]`,  also there is `[[:alnum:]]` which may come in handy.  And the first bit matches at least _two_ digits, not one, due to the `+`, and you force a dot at the end.  Please also let us know what the expected outcome is given the data you list.

Comment: Also please be more specific than "*it doesn't seem to work*": how did you apply it (in particular, what regex engine and what if any matching options did you use)? what did you expect to happen? what actually happened?

Comment: Are you reading this file with bash or grep or something else?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I was reading the file with 'while read' and passing the file as input. Then comparing each line to the regex I had built

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> at least one digit, followed by an arbitrary number of additional digits

`+` is already "one or more", so `[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]+` would require at least two. So `[[:digit:]]+`.

> words (at least one) each beginning with a capital letter or number, followed by any number of lower and upper case letters, numbers, or periods (.)

A capital or a number: `[[:upper:][:digit:]]`, no need for alternation (`|`) here as we can use both character classes inside the brackets at the same time.

`[[:alphabet:]]` isn't a valid character class, but there's `alpha` and `alnum` (for letters or numbers). The latter might be useful.

A single word: `[[:upper:][:digit:]][[:alnum:].]*`

Multiple words, with blanks in front of each (that takes care of the blank after the leading number too): `([[:blank:]]+[[:upper:][:digit:]][[:alnum:].]*)+`

And since you want to match the full line, add `^` and `$` to the ends, or use `grep -x`. You may want to add `[[:blank:]]*` to the end (before `$`) to allow for trailing blanks which are easy to leave by accident.

This would only print the first three lines of your sample input:

```
grep -E '^[[:digit:]]+([[:blank:]]+[[:upper:][:digit:]][[:alnum:].]*)+$' file
```

There's an online tool for playing with regexes in https://regex101.com/
which you may find useful for testing. Note that the above requires `grep -E` because of the `+` (the alternative is ugly), but I don't think regex101 allows to use plain basic `grep` regexes.

Comment: Or `grep -x` instead of the anchoring.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and clear explanation. Very appreciated